# is "the" required before "buyer" and "seller" in a contract?

Tags: definite-articles

Part of a contract introduces the seller and then says, "henceforth referred to as seller" and the buyer, and says, "henceforth referred to as buyer". I am noticing saying "the seller", "the buyer" too often rather than "seller", "buyer" makes the text look quite wordy. Is "the" article really required here?

Comment: “Buyer will give seller $3.14 on Tuesday; Seller will give buyer a hamburger today.”  This is perfectly understandable as headlinese or (as [John Feltz says](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/352525/26083)) legalese, so the answer is, “No, saying ‘the buyer’ and ‘the seller’ obviously is not really required.”  Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: Thank you @Scott, your comment was perfectly worded to be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legal contracts do this all the time.  "..., henceforth referred to as Seller", or "... ('Seller')" are a lawyer's way of defining a term within the scope of the contract.  Note that these are typically capitalized so as further make that distinction clear.

It's not a matter of shortening the contract by dropping the article, it's a matter of giving a placeholder proper name.